# AngularJS: Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope error (not injecting $scope in the service)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependencies

I seem to have a similar problem to many others working with AngularJS and dependency injection, which is: my AngularJS app gives an Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope error when I try to inject a service into a controller. Still, the only common mistake (and solution) I could find everywhere is that one should not inject $scope or $rootScope in the service function. Which I didn't do. The other issue that I found is that you should pass all dependencies as strings because they are not recognized by AngularJS due to minification (which I have in my dev ops now). Which I also did. So now the question is... what is wrong with my logic/structure and how can I solve this?

Here's the basic structure of my app:

```js
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial']);

angular
       .module('MyApp')
       .factory('Utils', function(){
  return {
   normalCase: function(str){
   result = '';
   str.split(' ').forEach(function(string, i){
    result += string[0].toUpperCase() + string.slice(1).toLowerCase();
    if(i<str.split(' ').length) result += ' ';
   });
   return result;
   }
  })
 .controller('AppController', ['$scope', '$mdDialog', 'Employee', 'Utils', '$http', 
   function($scope, Employee, Utils, $http, $mdDialog){
         $scope.employee.firstName = Utils.NormalCase(employee.firstName);
  }])
```

Also, the order of the files added in the index.html file is:

```html
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/models/Employee.js"></script>
<script src="js/models/Utils.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/AppController.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/EmployeeListController.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/ScorecardController.js"></script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The names of the dependencies to be injected into your controller need to be in the same order as the corresponding parameters in the controller function declaration (see [Angular's guide to Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#dependency-annotation)).

Your controller should be initialised like this:

```
.controller('AppController', ['$scope', '$http', '$mdDialog', 'Employee', 'Utils', 
    function($scope, $http, $mdDialog, Employee, Utils){
    $scope.employee.firstName = Utils.NormalCase(employee.firstName);
}])
```

It's also a common convention to list AngularJS dependencies first, followed by your custom ones.